# Why is this not off-topic on meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, specific-flag

I accidentally clicked into [Derivate vs. Derivative](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20898/derivate-vs-derivative) and flagged it as "off-topic". From my perspective, it does not appear to be about Mathematics Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network. And soon it ended up being declined. Maybe I flagged for the wrong reason? As the main thrust of the post is the terminology difference between derivate and derivative, it might be more suitable to be asked on MSE. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bold parts are what make this on-topic:

> I have encountered the term derivate standing in for derivative many times **in posts**. I usually **edit the post** to say derivative instead. But I am wondering, are their regions of the world where the term derivate is used instead?

Although the question could be phrased to make its on-topic-ness clearer. It's basically asking:

> Should I continue to edit posts to change "derivate" to "derivative"? Or is this term correct?

Comment: I believe the part of "editing post" is just the context of the question. The OP is mainly interested in the term difference.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Your interpretation is valid. Certainly I think the question would better fit on Math.SE or possibly even HSM.SE. And obviously, I can't speak for the 3 people who reviewed your flag. But I still think the question is *just barely* on-topic because it informs how one should edit posts on Math.SE.

Comment: Out of interest, what is HSM.SE?

Comment: @YuiToCheng [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)